# How do I calculate the intersection between a plane and a line in 3 dimensions?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given some lines in 3-D space, represented by a series of points (x, y, z) etc., and a plane represented by a point and a normal vector, how can I calculate if/where the plane intersects between two given points, which form my line?

I'm working on a programming project, and I'm not super well-versed in 3d geometry. I worked out my proof-of-concept in 2d, and am having trouble scaling it into this third dimension.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a line is represented by a series of points?

Comment: If you just want to know whether the segment between two points is intersected by the plane, check to see if the two points are on opposite sides of the plane. This is easily done by taking dot products of position vectors with the normal vector and comparing with the dot product of the normal with a position vector of a point in the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Pi$ be the plane containing $A$ normal to $N$. Let $L$ be the line passing through $B,C$.

$$\Pi=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3|(x-A)\cdot N=0\}$$
$$L=\{tB+(1-t)C|t\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

So, the intersection is a point $P=tB+(1-t)C$ satisfying the equation, i.e.

$$(tB+(1-t)C-A)\cdot N=0$$
$$t(B-C)\cdot N+(C-A)\cdot N=0$$
$$t=\frac{(A-C)\cdot N}{(B-C)\cdot N}$$
so the intersection in question is
$$P=\frac{(A-C)\cdot N}{(B-C)\cdot N}B+\frac{(B-A)\cdot N}{(B-C)\cdot N}C$$
... that is, unless $(B-C)\cdot N=0$, i.e. if $L$ is parallel to $\Pi$.

Comment: +1. Caveat to the proposer: $t(B-C)\cdot N+(C-A)\cdot N=0$ has no solution if $(B-C)\cdot N=0\ne (C-A)\cdot N$. That means $L$ is parallel to, but not in $\Pi$. Every $t$ is a solution of $t(B-C)\cdot N+(C-A)\cdot N=0$ if $(B-C)\cdot N=0=(C-A)\cdot N$.That means $L$ is $in $ $\Pi$.